# IOS how to compare dictionary array item in the index with another NSarray index item

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, nsdictionary

I have a Dictionary item call "feeds". within the feeds i have a key named "SignatureNumber". This key inside contain a list of array items.

When i log it out it looks like this.

```
Final signature : (
        {
        SignatureNumber = 7075274256;
    }
)
```

Now, i have another NSarray call "information" which contains a list of items. I want to compare the item inside the index of this two array.

Currently, this is my codes.

```
   for (int i=0; i <information.count; i++) {
   for (NSDictionary *feed in feeds) {

    if ([feed[@"SignatureNumber"] containsObject:[information objectAtIndex:i]]) {
        badIPCount++;
    }else{
        goodIPCount++;
    }
   }
}
```

The error is this codes i have does not compare the items in "feeds" with "information". Why? Please help me to adjust my codes. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show full of `feeds` and `information` log?

Comment: the feeds log is above. regarding the information data is: NSarray deepsightSig = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"2802504", @"752286", @"752288", @"752287",
               @"3763718", @"696585", @"752285", @"7075274256",nil];

Comment: My feeds is a NSmutable array which contains dictionary with key call SignatureNumber

Comment: The codes run smoothly but didn't get the hit when both array contains the same item.

Comment: You should use 2 loops, 1 for  `feeds`, and 1 for `information`

Comment: can u show me the codes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (NSDictionary * dict in feeds) {

  for (NSNumber * number in deepsightSig) {

    long idFeed = [dict[@"SignatureNumber"] longValue];  /// if your id is too large, using NSString instead.
    long idSig = [number longValue];   /// like NSString = [number stringValue];

    if (idFeed == idSig) { /// if using NSString, it should be: "if ([idFeed isEqualToString:idSig])"
      badIPCount++;
    }
    else {
      goodIPCount++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it gave an error saying: array subscript is not an integer on line"long idFeed = [dict[@"SignatureNumber"] longValue];  "

Comment: Can you please NSLog(@"%@",dict) after `for (NSDictionary * dict in feeds)`, and show me the result

Comment: sry. the codes above is comparing the data inside the array or the index number?

Comment: My code? My code compares between number in `SignatureNumber = 7075274256;` and number in `deepsightSig`. If I misunderstood, please explain more about your problem.